# R igraph colour edge according to logical flag

Tags: r, igraph

i have a graph where one of the edge attribute is the correlation between 2 vertices.  I would like to colour the edges on my plot differently according to whether the correlation is positive or negative.
I tried using edge.color=c("red","blue")[E(mygraph)$correlation>=0] in the plot attributes but i end up with only the first 2 edges showing, one red, one blue, and no others...
See this simplified example:

```
myedges<-data.frame(From=c("item1","item1","item1","item2","item2","item3"), 
                To=c("item2","item3","item4","item3","item4","item4"), 
                correlation=c(0.4,0.1,-0.6,-0.3,0.5,0.8))
mygraph<-graph_from_data_frame(myedges, directed=FALSE)
plot(mygraph, 
     edge.width=E(mygraph)$correlation*50,
     edge.color=c("red","blue")[E(mygraph)$correlation>=0])
```

what am i doing wrong...?

Comment: You are incorrectly subsetting the vector of colours. Look at the output of `c("red","blue")[E(mygraph)$correlation>=0]`. You could try `ifelse(E(mygraph)$correlation>=0, 'red','blue')` or `c('red','blue')[(E(mygraph)$correlation < 0) +1]`

Comment: perfect!  thanks very much.