# Set edge colours based on edge relationships ggnet2, igraph r

Tags: r, igraph, ggnetwork

I am plotting a graph with ggnet2. I would like to plot edges based on the value of edge relationship. Until now I was able only to represent edge value on the edge, below you can see an extract of my code:

```
ggnet2(max_spann_tree3 ,size =  nlav1,size.cut = 4, edge.size = 1, edge.color = "grey", edge.label = E(max_spann_tree2)$weight,edge.label.size = 2, color = "he1", color.legend = "industry", palette = "Set3")
```

Here the values that I used for the edge label in the my code:

```
edge.label=E(max_spann_tree2)$weight
> edge.label
  [1] 0.4047619 0.3703704 0.5483871 0.4727273 0.5510204 0.6078431 0.5490196 0.6451613 0.7254902 0.4489796
 [11] 0.6000000 0.4074074 0.5714286 0.6973684 0.8181818 0.8701299 0.6578947 0.4210526 0.5128205 0.4909091
 [21] 0.6037736 0.3793103 0.4166667 0.3750000 0.5000000 0.3000000 0.5660377 0.5263158 0.5000000 0.4634146
```

I would like to plot the same graph, but setting a colour scale based on the edge's relationships that are included in the range 0.2-0.9, without representing them in the edge's label.
I tried with this: https://briatte.github.io/ggnet/#edge-size-and-color, without success.
here my attempt:

```
>set.edge.attribute(max_spann_tree3 , "color", ifelse(max_spann_tree3 %e%"E(max_spann_tree2)$weight"> 0.5, "black"&& max_spann_tree3 %e%"E(max_spann_tree2)$weight"< 0.5, "red"))
> ggnet2(max_spann_tree3 ,size =  nlav1,size.cut = 4, edge.size = 1, edge.color = "color", edge.label.size = 2, color = "he1", color.legend = "industry", palette = "Set3")

> Error in if (!is_col(edge.color)) { : 
>       missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

any suggestions?

Comment: what does `get.edge.attribute(max_spann_tree3 , "color")` return? it sounds like you have `NA` values in there.

Comment: are `max_spann_tree3` and `max_spann_tree2` just copies of the same graph? or how was `max_spann_tree3` created?

Comment: As you grasp `get.edge.attribute(max_spann_tree3 , "color")` return NA.  I use `max_spann_tree3<-asNetwork(max_spann_tree2)` and
`max_spann_tree3 %v% "he1" <- he1` just to set the node colour as you can see in my code

Comment: In that case it should have the same edge weights as the original graph, so you should be able to call `E(max_spann_tree3)$color<-ifelse(E(max_spann_tree3)$weight > 0.5, "black", "red")` without need to reference the original.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but I partially solve with this `ifelse(E(mygraph)$correlation>=0, 'red','blue')`, founded in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315988/r-igraph-colour-edge-according-to-logical-flag?rq=1. Any suggestions to use more colour to represent edge values? Should I use another function instead of ifelse, right?

Comment: Sure, can you edit your question with the specifics?

Comment: This is the function I used to plot the edge values with only two colours:  `gradoprox<-ifelse(E(max_spann_tree2)$weight>=0.6, 'red','blue'`,               where max_spann_tree2=max_spann_tree3 in terms of edge values.  `ggnet2(max_spann_tree3 ,size =  nlav1,size.cut = 4, edge.size = 1, edge.color = gradoprox, edge.label.size = 2, color = "he1", color.legend = "industry", palette = "Set3")`.I would like to plot it with more colours

Comment: I have provided a general answer below. If that does not meet your needs please edit your _original question_ with the specifics (so that others can see it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to color your graph edges by their weight, you can use the `cut` function along with its `labels` argument to assign a color attribute to your edges.

```
library(igraph)
library(GGally)

#simulate a weighted network
set.seed(1)
tree_graph<-random.graph.game(20, p=.2)
E(tree_graph)$weight<-sample(seq(0,1,0.01), ecount(tree_graph), replace=T)


#add colors to edges according to what bin their weight falls in
E(tree_graph)$color<-as.character(cut(E(tree_graph)$weight, 
                                            breaks=c(0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1), 
                                            labels=c("yellow", "orange", "red", "black")))

#plot graph, verifying that colors match edge weights
ggnet2(tree_graph, edge.color = "color", edge.label = "weight")
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to print colour with `E(tree_graph)$color`. The only problem is that R returns me: `Error in ggnet2(max_spann_tree3, size = nlav1, size.cut = 4, label.size = 4,  : 
  incorrect edge.color value`

Comment: Make sure you are converting the `cut` results to class character before assigning them to `E(tree_graph)$color`